# Trying to use gSoap with WCF and WSHttpBinding

Tags: c++, linux, wcf, gsoap, ws-addressing

I am attempting to use the gSoap library to talk to a WCF server with the WSHttpBinding.  I seem to be running into a problem with the WS-Addressing plugin for gSoap.  When I enable the WS-Addressing plugin, by using #import "wsa5.h" I can no longer compile.  Now, there are unresolved symbols in soapC.cpp.  The first error is in soap_getelement(soap*, int*).  The error is SOAP_TYPE_*wsa5*_IsReferenceParameter.  This is my first attempt with using gSoap.  Any advice is appreciated.

gSoap Version 2.8.4

Comment: I think my problem is related to this ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageversion.soap12wsaddressing10.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add the WSA part to your Typemap file, then in your wsdl2h command specify it with the -t parameter.

i.e:

```
wsdl2h -o target.h -t EditedTypemap.dat target.wsdl
```

You can just copy the standard Typemap.dat from your gSOAP directory and edit it so it looks like the following:

```
wsa = <http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing>

SOAP_ENV__Header =\
#import "wsa.h"\n\
struct SOAP_ENV__Header\n\
{\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__MessageID    wsa__MessageID 0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__RelatesTo *  wsa__RelatesTo 0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__From *       wsa__From      0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__ReplyTo *    wsa__ReplyTo   0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__FaultTo *    wsa__FaultTo   0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__To           wsa__To        0;\n\
   mustUnderstand _wsa__Action       wsa__Action    0;\n\
};
```

Then rerun wsdl2h as I mentioned above. Hope this works for you!
gSOAP is a great toolkit, just a little finnicky to get into.

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work for you, you can look in you gSOAP directory

    `gsoap-2.8/gsoap/doc/wsa/html/wsa_0.html`

in my case as I'm using  gSOAP 2.8. This document gives clear guides for using the WSA plugin and includes samlpe code.

Comment: Thanks!  However, that code is already in my soapStub.h file without modification to my typemap.dat.  I took a packet capture and it looks like there are some tags in the wsaw namespace coming from the WCF side.  I took a closer look and it refers to the 2006/05 spec :(

Comment: Ah I see. I'm going to keep this in mind as I am developing a gSOAP client and server and I'm not having success compiling the gSOAP 2.8 calc++ samples. So I will be delving pretty deep into gSOAP from here. If I find out anything that may be of use to you I'll make sure to PM you. Best of luck!